# apex string processing

Tags: apex, string

I have a requirement to replace specific text separated by a delimeter (delimeter can be , : ; etc). Example 1 : In string 'Sonu,krishna,Siva, pintoo' , need to replace specific token/text "Pintoo" , resultant string value will be 'Sonu, Krishna,Siva' .
Example 2 : In string 'Padma;Rama;Lakshmi;Aruna;Usha', replace specific token 'Rama' , resultant string value will be 'Padma;Lakshmi;Aruna;Usha' ( Removed token Rama)

I tried it via split() method and rejoining the string etc, however looking for if there is any simplest way to get this done

Comment: Have you checked the [`String` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our last conversation, I write this code for you

```
        string input = 'Sonu,krishna,Siva,pintoo,pintoosh';
        string token = 'pintoo';
        string output = '';
        List<string> DelimeterList = new List<string>{',',':',';'};
        string Delimeter;
        for(String Deli : DelimeterList){
            if(input.contains(Deli)){
                Delimeter = Deli;
            }
        }
         
        List<string> Names = input.split(Delimeter);
        if(Names.contains(token)){
            Names.remove(Names.indexOf(token));
        }
        else{
            system.debug('The input string does not contain the token');
        }
        
        for(String N : Names){
            output+=N+Delimeter;
        }
        
        output = output.removeEnd(Delimeter);
        
        system.debug(output);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response .  Looks like pattern & matcher classes also should work fine for my requirement .

Answer (score 0):

`Split()` method is equally appropriate but you can also use `replace()` method.

Example:

```
string s1 = 'Sonu,krishna,Siva,pintoo';
s1 = s1.replace(',pintoo','');
system.debug(s1);
//Output : Sonu,krishna,Siva
```

Also visit this website for more method : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Comment: I guess replace may not work . For e.g :   If String s1 = 'Sonu,krishna,Siva,pintoo,pintoosh', I just wanted to replace exact whole word 'pintoo' only and don't want to replace pintoosh. After replacing, resultant string value should be  'Sonu,krishna,Siva,pintoosh' . ( Please note, pintoosh is not remo

Comment: Parag, Thank you for your response . Please let me know how to replace whole word only ?  For e.g : If String s1 = 'Sonu,krishna,Siva,pintoo,pintoosh', I just wanted to replace exact whole word 'pintoo' only and don't want to replace pintoosh. After replacing, resultant string value should be 'Sonu,krishna,Siva,pintoosh' . ( Please note, pintoosh is not removed)

Comment: @Hemant-2
In that case split() method would be best option as because we have specific delimeter by which we can split the string and we can use contains() method on list so that it don't throw an error

Comment: Also delimeter can be comma (,), colon (:), semicolon (;) . For object1 (e,g: Account) records, delimeter may be comma and for object2 (e.g: Quote) records delimeter may be semicolon. How do I join the string using same delimeter ? e.g : String s1 = 'Sonu,krishna,Siva,pintoo,pintoosh', resultant string value should be  'Sonu,krishna,Siva,pintoosh' (removed pintoo )  e.g: String s2 =  'Padma;Rama;Lakshmi;Aruna;Usha', resultant string value should be 'Padma;Lakshmi;Aruna;Usha' ( removed Rama and joined the string using same delimeter .  Could you please share sample code ?